# Making the python program `gnome-terminal` independent

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a python script which starts different programs kept in different folders in different terminals. Each program do not end once it is started and I have to start four programs. Therefore I decided to start each program independently in different terminals by using `subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "gradle run"])` instead of starting a program(which will not end) by `os.system('gradle run')` . Now I want to make this program `gnome-terminal` independent so that it can be used on other Operating Systems as well how to proceed.
Here is the code for whole program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import socket
import urllib
import subprocess


path_apphome = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/..'
os.chdir(path_apphome)
# os.system('ls')

def checkportopen(port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    return sock.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1', port)) == 0

def mkapps():
    if not os.path.isdir(path_apphome + '/data'): os.makedirs(path_apphome + '/data')
    if not os.path.isdir(path_apphome + '/data/mcp-8100'): os.makedirs(path_apphome + '/data/mcp-8100')
    if not os.path.isdir(path_apphome + '/data/mcp-8100/apps'): os.makedirs(path_apphome + '/data/mcp-8100/apps')

def run_mcp():
    subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "gradle run"])

def run_loader():
    os.system('cd ../yacy_grid_loader')
    subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "gradle run"])

def run_crawler():
    os.system('cd ../yacy_grid_crawler')
    subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "gradle run"])

def run_parser():
    os.system('cd ../yacy_grid_parser')
    subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "gradle run"])


if not checkportopen(9200):
    print "Elasticsearch is not running"
    mkapps()
    elasticversion = 'elasticsearch-5.6.5'
    if not os.path.isfile(path_apphome + '/data/mcp-8100/apps/' + elasticversion + '.tar.gz'):
        print('Downloading ' + elasticversion)
        urllib.urlretrieve ('https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/' + elasticversion + '.tar.gz', path_apphome + '/data/mcp-8100/apps/' + elasticversion + '.tar.gz')
    if not os.path.isdir(path_apphome + '/data/mcp-8100/apps/elasticsearch'):
        print('Decompressing' + elasticversion)
        os.system('tar xfz ' + path_apphome + '/data/mcp-8100/apps/' + elasticversion + '.tar.gz -C ' + path_apphome + '/data/mcp-8100/apps/')
        os.rename(path_apphome + '/data/mcp-8100/apps/' + elasticversion, path_apphome + '/data/mcp-8100/apps/elasticsearch')
    # run elasticsearch
    print('Running Elasticsearch')
    os.chdir(path_apphome + '/data/mcp-8100/apps/elasticsearch/bin')
    os.system('nohup ./elasticsearch &')

os.chdir(path_apphome)

if checkportopen(15672):
    print "RabbitMQ is Running"
    print "If you have configured it according to YaCy setup press N"
    print "If you have not configured it according to YaCy setup or Do not know what to do press Y"
    n=raw_input()
    if(n=='Y' or n=='y'):
        os.system('service rabbitmq-server stop')

if not checkportopen(15672):
    print "rabbitmq is not running"
    os.system('python bin/start_rabbitmq.py')

subprocess.call('bin/update_all.sh')

if not checkportopen(2121):
    print "ftp server is not Running"

if not checkportopen(8100):
    print "yacy_grid_mcp is not running,running yacy_grid_mcp in new terminal"
    run_mcp()


if not checkportopen(8200):
    print "yacy_grid_loader is not running,running yacy_grid_loader in new terminal"
    run_loader()


if not checkportopen(8300):
    print "yacy_grid_crawler is not running,running yacy_grid_crawler in new terminal"
    run_crawler()


if not checkportopen(8500):
    print "yacy_grid_parser is not running,running yacy_grid_parser in new terminal"
    run_parser()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are managing path is unix-specific:

> /data/mcp-8100/apps/elasticsearch/bin'

If you want to be platform independent, you need to use OS primive:

```
os.path.join('data','mcp-8100','apps','elasticsearch','bin')
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Can you please suggest something which makes it independent of `gnome-terminal` ?

Comment: os.path.join makes it independent from gnome-terminal. This can be used for windows as well

Comment: just pass the -e argument with system run. os.system('gradle run -e')

Comment: @kpie when using `os.system('gradle run -e')`  build is failed for program which I want to run.

Comment: @Luc I want to remove `subprocess.call(['gnome-terminal', '-e', "gradle run"])` instead of using `gnome-terminal` can we use a more generic term to execute the `gradle run` command in Terminal on Mac  or cmd on windows. Do not worry about path that can be modified according to your suggestion.